# Как добавить смерть персонажа в игре?

Tags: python, pygame

Создаю игру где главный герой будет убивать противников и за их убийство будут выдавать очки. Но при смерти противника очки выдаются всё равно (я наношу удары после смерти когда его хп меньше 0 (goblin.health <= 0) и очки начисляются как бы он умер еще раз). Хочу исправить ошибку, чтобы очки выдавались единожды, но либо их не выдают либо их выдают даже после его смерти.

```
        class enemy(object):
walkRight = [pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png")
             ,pygame.image.load("gobling2.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling2.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png")
             ,pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png"),pygame.image.load("gobling.png")]
ba = [pygame.image.load("ba1.png"),pygame.image.load("ba2.png"),pygame.image.load("ba3.png"),pygame.image.load("ba4.png"),pygame.image.load("ba5.png")]
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
    self.x = x + 100
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.end = end
    self.path = [self.x, self.end]
    self.walkCount = 0
    self.attackCount = 0
    self.vel = 3
    self.hitbox = (self.x , self.y , 66, 64)
    self.health = 10
    self.visible = True
    self.attack = False
    self.death = False
    self.standing = True
    self.playing = True
    self.death = False
def draw(self,win):
    if self.visible:
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 30:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if self.attackCount + 1 >= 20:
            self.attackCount = 0

        if self.standing :
            win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //5], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        if (self.attack):
            win.blit(self.ba[self.attackCount //4], (self.x,self.y))
            self.attackCount += 1
            if man.attack == False:
                self.attack = False
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0] + 10, self.hitbox[1] - 10, 250, 20))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0] + 10, self.hitbox[1] - 10, 250 - (25 * (10 - self.health)), 20))
        self.hitbox = (self.x , self.y , 66, 40)

def hit(self):
    if self.health >= 0:
        self.health -= man.damage
        if self.health - man.damage < -1:
            self.health = -1
            self.visible = False
        if man.poison == True:
            self.health += 0.5
    if self.health <= 0:
        self.playing = False
    if self.playing == False:
        self.visible = False
    if self.playing == False:
        self.death == True"""
```

Comment: Добавить статус смерти и если у противника < 0 хитпоинтов, то ставить этот статус в true. И перед каждым ударом проверять этот статус, если false - урон проходит, если true - противник мертв

Comment: Да но к примеру у врага 250 хп, а игрок наносит на 1 уровне 40 урона и отсюда следует,что ему нужно нанести 7 ударов и хр = -30,а на 2 уровне урон = 50 и хр поменяется

Comment: Нет разницы какой урон и сколько здоровья, проверять здоровье и менять либо не менять статус нужно после каждого удара

Comment: но тогда выйдет код на подобии if hp - damage <= 0: score += 5 и вы этом случае любой удар после этого будет давать score. Если я не прав ответь пожалуйста